# Getting some dupes when trying to merge two data frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I Googled for a solution, before posting here, and I tried a couple different ideas, but nothing seemed to work. The highlighted parts are the problem. In the final DF I want one instance of 12674.4 and one instance of 21008.21

Here is df1.

[image]

Here is df2.

[image]

Here is the final merged data frame.

[image]

I don't think I can really de-dupe each data frame before doing the merge, because they are already de-duped. Any thoughts on how to handle this issue?

Here is my merge code.

```
df_merge = pd.merge(df_exp, 
                df_rev,
                left_on=['SID','Year'],
                right_on=['PID','Year'],
                how='inner')
print(df_merge.shape)
```

I think the final result should be something like this.

[image]

So, if PID, Sub_Market, State, Year and Expense are duplicated, divide Expense in half. I think that solves the problem because I can assume that Expense is spread evenly between two different records of 'Site_Name'.

Comment: _How_ are you merging the dataframes?

Comment: Which row do you want to keep? Rows 2 and 3 have different `site_name`s and revenues, for example. Which one is the "right" one?

Comment: You can use the `subset` parameter of `pd.drop_duplicates` to drop duplicates in terms of the columns that you're merging on.

Comment: When merging/joining, you will get 2 values since there are 2 2018 and 2019 in df2. You have to drop the ones you do not want from df2 if you are merging by year. Unless you add a 3rd column eg sitename to your df1 to distinguish the observations

Comment: Sorry, that 1, 2, 3 came from the fill-down in Excel. Also, I don't think it's a drop_duplicates thing. For instance, I just tried this, but nothing changed: df_merged = df_merged.sort_values(['PID', 'Sub_Market', 'State', 'Year'],ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['Expense'], keep='first').reset_index()

Comment: The problem is the multiple `site_name` per `year` in df2 not the duplicate `expense` in df1.

Comment: @ Onyambu, yeah, that sounds reasonable, but I don't have a 'site_name' in DF1. Somehow I need to sum and group_by the values in DF2, not drop them.

Comment: @ASH Can you post your code for merging?

Comment: I actually thought I had it in my original post, but I just realized I forgot to share that.

Comment: You never tagged me here so thats why I havent responded (There was a space between the @tag and my name). What exactly do you mean by `sum` them? ie Could you post your expected output. In that way we could be of help

Comment: I just updated my post again. So, if PID, Sub_Market, State, Year and Expense are duplicated, divide Expense in half. I think that solves the problem because I can assume that Expense is spread evenly between two different records of 'Site_Name'. That's plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you could do:

```
df_merge['Expense'] = df_merge.groupby(['PID', 'sub_market', 'state', 'Year', 'Expense'])['Expense'].\
                               transform(lambda x: x/x.count())

   SID  Year    Expense  PID  ...        site_name state YTD_Revenue   Revenue
0  100  2017  50674.950  100  ...  HOUSE_RETAIL_21    UT    510602.8  899061.8
1  100  2018   6337.200  100  ...     HOUSE_RETAIL    UT    320649.1  324190.8
2  100  2018   6337.200  100  ...  HOUSE_RETAIL_21    UT    634509.4  593213.6
3  100  2019  10504.105  100  ...     HOUSE_RETAIL    UT   1262068.5  956957.0
4  100  2019  10504.105  100  ...  HOUSE_RETAIL_21    UT    163976.5  110292.3
5  100  2020  14241.510  100  ...     HOUSE_RETAIL    UT    161396.0  123000.9
```

NOTE:
Next time upload the text version of the data instead of an image

Comment: Works perfect. Sorry for not clarifying things at the beginning. It took me a while to realize what was going on here. All set now!